# Finding index of element to be inserted in large sorted set--memory issues with bisect?

Tags: sorting, indexing

Given a large sorted list `l` of size `n` and an element `x`, I want to find the index of `x` if it is to be inserted in `l`.

The obvious way to go about it is through bisection:

```
def bis(l, x):
    m = len(l)
    if m <= 1:
        return m
    elif l[m//2] < x:
        return m//2+bis(l[m//2:], x)
    else:
        return bis(l[0:m//2], x)
```

This is similar to the implementation of the `bisect.bisect` method and should run in $O(\log n)$.

However, when the lists get large, processing the bisected lists take forever and the code runs approximately linearly.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean "takes forever"? If the list is sorted, then even a ten million record list will only take 24 checks, which should be incredibly fast. The real issue here feels like you trying to do this using recursion and list expansion (like your `l[m/2:]`) instead of just using low/high indices, checking `l[(low+high)/2]`, and updating those boundaries until low==high.

Comment: And of course, the first rule in programming is "don't roll your own code unless you're the only person to ever need to do this", which for a binary search is very much not the case. There are lots of good tutorials on the web that explain how to efficiently implement binary search in Python to find.